# How to restart app on exit?

Tags: ios, swift

I have just started learning Swift and Xcode all together and I don't quite get it how I can restart someone exits / jumps back into it. As of right now when someone exits the app and jumps back instead of the app restarting from zero, his session is resumed. Does anyone know how this could be done?

Comment: Why would you want the user to start all over just because they briefly switched away from your app?

Comment: @rmaddy I am just curious on how it may be done.

Answer (score 2):

In your info.plist set the value "Application does not run in background" to "YES"

Here is a helpful link with pictures for doing this: http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-kill-your-app-when-it-enters-background-mode/

Answer (score -2):

When your app is n background mode , there is no problem, the session still active. 
But when you kill the app completely , you session is dropped automatically , So you have different choice to do:
For example, you can save the credential in keychain access, and then when you start your app, you get those credentials from keychains access and you call you server to get your session 
Thus the user will be conformable to get his session again

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked